# How to add an "INCLUDE" part in an Index Created as a part of CONSTRAINT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing, query-optimization

I am going through the execution plan of a `tsql` query.

[image]

There is a `key LookUp (Clustered)` in the plan. To avoid this `Key LookUp`, I tried to Include a column (`Status_Ind`) to The Index (The Index used in execution plan). But I realize that optimizer is using two Indexes, One the Primary Key index and the 2nd one, an index automatically created as a part of a  Constraint (A UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED Index). I find no way to add an **include** part in this Index.

How do we add an INCLUDE in an index which is automatically created (through CONSTRAINTS)?
I am really a beginner in Query optimization..

Comment: i was going through this,http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa224827%28SQL.80%29.aspx.
But did not find a way.

Answer (score 1):

If you find that the key lookup is really a big deal (and it may or may not be), you can create a unique index instead of a unique constraint. In SQL Server, the two are the same (unique constraints are enforced via a unique index). You can place include columns on a unique index, so you should be set.